# How do I create a block with a given binding in ruby?

Tags: ruby, binding, block

I'm trying to write a version of `assert_difference` that will accept a hash as an argument, so that instead of writing

```
assert_difference 'thing1', 1 do
  assert_difference ['thing2a', 'thing2b'], 2 do
    assert_difference 'thing3', -3 do
      # some triple-indented code
    end
  end
end
```

I can write

```
assert_difference 'thing1' => 1, ['thing2a', 'thing2b'] => 2, 'thing3' => 3 do
  # some single-indented code
end
```

I've got as far as

```
def assert_difference_with_hash_support(expression, difference = 1, message = nil, &block)
  if expression.is_a? Hash
    expression.each do |expr, diff|
      block = lambda do
        assert_difference_without_hash_support expr, diff, &block
      end
    end
    block.call
  else
    assert_difference_without_hash_support(expression, difference, message, &block)
  end
end
alias_method_chain :assert_difference, :hash_support
```

but this doesn't work because assert_difference uses the binding of the block when it evaluates the expression.  What I'd like to do is to create a new block with the original binding - something like so:

```
    b = block.send :binding
    expression.each do |expr, diff|
      block = lambda(b) do
        assert_difference_without_hash_support expr, diff, &block
      end
    end
    block.call
```

but I haven't seen a way of creating a new block with anything other than the current binding.  How do I create a block with a given binding?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am missing something, but I think you are trying to use very complicated features of ruby, while they are unnecessary for solving your problem.

My solution would be:

```
def assert_hash(hash, &block)
  if hash.length > 1
    assert_difference(*hash.shift) do
      assert_hash(hash, &block)
    end
  else
    assert_difference(*hash.first, &block)
  end
end
```

Of course it is missing aliasing, but that's not the point.

EDIT:

As of creating blocks with custom bindings the answer is: no. But you can call chunks of code with different binding, either caught with `binding` method, or just by providing object that has binding related with it.

You can either use `eval` for this purpose (it accepts Binding object as a second argument) or better `instance_eval`, `class_eval`, `instance_exec` and `class_exec`. You can start your digging at [Jay Fields' Thoughts blog entry](http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/09/ruby-instanceexec-aka-instanceeval.html).